# How to check Oracle database query

Tags: struts-1

Q. How to check Oracle database query running at backend while clicking on update button on my page(Struts 1.x project)??

Thanks in advance

Comment: … How are you making the query? Do you have access to the DB logs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.